# change map view without change position

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a map with a default marker (address of the connected user) and other markers (addresseses passed in array) and I have a select input with addresses passed in array, and I like when select option change the view of the map change on the marker of selected option,
Is it possible to implement this without change of the default position of the default marker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Just create a new **[Google Maps Javascript API Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#top_of_page)** using a **new marker variable** when your select input's **'change'** event has been fired.

You can take a look at the sample code below:

```js
      var map;
      function initMap() {
        var defaultLoc = { "lat" : 37.7749295, "lng" :-122.4194155 };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: defaultLoc,
          zoom: 8
        });
        var markerDefault = new google.maps.Marker({
          position : defaultLoc,
          map : map
          
        });
        document.getElementById('menuLoc').addEventListener('change', function(){
          var that = this;
          var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
          geocoder.geocode({          
            address: that.value
          }, function(result, status){
            if ( status === 'OK' ) {
              var newMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position : result[0].geometry.location,
                map: map
              });
              map.setCenter(result[0].geometry.location);
            }           
          });
        });
      }
```

```css
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #floating-panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 25%;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #FFF;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
        line-height: 30px;
        padding-left: 10px;
      }
```

```html
    <div id="floating-panel">
      <select id="menuLoc">
      <option value="fresno, ca, USA">Fresno</option>
      <option value="sacramento, ca, usa">Sacramento</option>
      <option value="carson city">Carson City</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCzjs-bUR6iIl8yGLr60p6-zbdFtRpuXTQ&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
```

Hope it could and happy coding!